# Wrapping Text Around a Sidebar

Tags: css, sidebar, word-wrap

I'm trying to write a code for my first skin. I've already written the sidebar code and it works fine, and I've gotten the text on the screen with it. However, the sidebar is overlapping the text as opposed to sitting in juxtaposition with it. You can view it [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/cheyhiful/bBs32/10/)

My sidebar code is:

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(153, 230,255);
    color: black;
    top: 5px;
    left:5px;
}
```

You can view the rest of it [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/cheyhiful/bBs32/10/)

Can someone please help me figure out what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The offending line is `position: fixed;`. If you remove that, the body text will wrap around the sidebar like you want.

Comment: Also, remove `style= "float: right;"` in the HTML for the sidebar element. It will override any changes you make in the CSS file.